# Why don't pointer point to right packet header when I capture network packet?

Tags: c, pointers, tcp, libpcap

I used libpcap to capture network packet.My code was

`adhandle = pcap_open_live(wlan0,65536, PCAP_OPENFLAG_PROMISCUOUS, 1000,errbuf);/*open interface*/
    pcap_next_ex(adhandle, &pheader, &pkt_data);/*capture packet*/
    ip_header* ih = (ip_header*)(pkt_data+14);
    tcp_header* th = (tcp_header*)(ih+20);`

In above code, pkt_data point to ether header. And I wanted ih point to ip header and th point to tcp header.

Well,I used gdb to debug. I printed these three pointers. Pkt_data point to `0x603cd0`. Ih point to `0x603cde`.Ih point to right place. Because ih minus pkt_data is `0xe` which equal to 14.

But th point to `0x603ebe`.Why th point to `0x603ebe`?I think th should point to `0x603cf2`.For `0x603cf2` is equal to ih plus 20 ?

If I use `tcp_header* th = (tcp_header*)(pkt_data+34);`.The th will be   `0x603cf2` which is right place.Why use `pkt_data+34` will work. But`ih+20` don't work.

I am very confused about it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ip_header* ih = (ip_header*)(pkt_data+14);
> tcp_header* th = (tcp_header*)(ih+20);
> ```

That's how pointer arithmetic works in C: the address is increased such that `th` points 20 `ip_header` worth of data away from where you started. Which means the address is increased with `20 * sizeof ip_header`.

Instead of that, you want to jump **20 bytes** which you can do using:

```
tcp_header* th = (char *)ih + 20;
```

Comment: Well,I tried your answear.But it don't work.The `th` still be `0x603ebe`. `0x603ebe` minus `0x603cde` is `0x1e0` which equals to  480.And the `sizeof ip_header` is 20 bytes. So `20 * sizeof ip_header`should be 400.

Comment: @user3589797 You must be doing something wrong that is not obvious from what you have posted.

Comment: I made a mistake when I try your answear. Your answear is right.Thank you very much.